# How to auto scroll downListView control when update new item- android studio

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have listview for my chat page....whenever i type new message in listview it not automatically scrolled down at botton.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_page"
    tools:context=".Chatbox">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/send"
         />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/typemessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Type a message..." />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/sendbutton"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/listmessages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I add new text in listview then it should go to bottom of the page to see new messsage

Comment: Use `listview.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());` after adding every item

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out. But i suggest you to use to recyclerview instead of listview for Chat module.

```
private void scrollToBottom() {
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Cool please accept this as answer so that it is easy for others who are trying out the same.

Comment: Oki you need to click on "Arrow Mark" at the left to accept this as answer